# Why doctrine ORM is used in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Can any one tell me what is the reason behind that. Why most of people uses doctrine in symfony2. Any specific reason behind that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: One of the most common and challenging tasks for any application involves persisting and reading information to and from a database. Although the Symfony Framework doesn't integrate any component to work with databases, it provides tight integration with a third-party library called Doctrine. Doctrine's sole goal is to give you powerful tools to make database interactions easy and flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Because a significant part of any web application are CRUD operations. And making CRUD operations with ORM are much faster. And Doctrine2 is de-facto the best ORM library for PHP.